# Typescript over loading to support both callback and async await

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How i have the below code block

```js
type RCB < T > = (error: Error | null, result: T) => void
interface ListItem {
  name: string
  creationDate: Date
}

//How to overload this in typescript such that it suits both methods of accessing( examples below)
async function listRows(): Promise < ListItem[] > {
  return Promise.resolve([{name:"test",creationDate: new Date() }])
}

//----------- Method 1 -------------------
// Call listRows() with Async/Await 

async function getRows() {
  try {
    let res = await listRows()
    console.log(res)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

getRows()
//-------------------------------

//------------- Method 2 -----------
// Call listRows() with callback 

listRows((e, res) => {
  console.log(e, res)
})

//-----------------------------------
```

the question is how to apply Typescript overload syntax on `listRows` such that, both are supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with generics and a ternary operator on the return value, or with overloading. I went with overloading as in my preferred method:

```js
function listRows(cb:(e:Error|null, res?:ListItem[])=>void):void;
function listRows(): Promise < ListItem[] >;
function listRows(cb?:(e:Error|null, res?:ListItem[])=>void): Promise < ListItem[] > | void {
  if (cb) {
    cb(null, [{name:"test",creationDate: new Date()}] );
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve([{name:"test",creationDate: new Date() }]);
  }
}
```

As a side note, if you are going to return a `Promise`, there's no need to create an `async` function, because an `async` function creates and returns a `Promise` by itself, so you are double creating a `Promise`.

In this case it returns a `Promise` or a `void` depending on the argument.

The way to do this is two ways:

1. Create the code of the function that you want to overload, so you can see all the possible arguments and returns, and then write all the overload functions. In this case you could notice that you don't need to return a `Promise` when using a callback, so the `Promise` (hence the `async` function) is optional.
2. Directly write the overload functions if you already know what you need, and then implement the code to fit the functions.